# Retrieve data from another table / subquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g

SQL # 1 works like I expect it to.  However, I need to add 3 fields (account, journal_id, and journal_date to the results from another table.  SQL # 2 returns the 3 fields I need in the results to SQL #1.  It also returns the asset_id field because the results from SQL #2 must relate to the asset_ID field in SQL #1.

I'm wondering if a subquery in SQL #1 will return the 3 fields.  I'm new to sql and don't know where to start with a subquery in SQL #1.  Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

SQL #1

```
SELECT 
pa.BUSINESS_UNIT, 
pa.DESCR,
pdr.DEPTID, 
pdr.ASSET_ID, 
pdr.ACCOUNT_AD, 
pdr.BOOK,

MAX(CASE WHEN (pdr.FISCAL_YEAR =2014 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =11) THEN  pdr.DEPR END) as CURRENT_AMT,
MAX(CASE WHEN (pdr.FISCAL_YEAR =2104 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =10) THEN pdr.DEPR  END) as PRIOR_AMT

FROM PS_ASSET pa

INNER JOIN PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 
ON pa.ASSET_ID = pdr.ASSET_ID
AND pa.BUSINESS_UNIT = pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT

WHERE 
pa.BUSINESS_UNIT=A0465
AND pdr.BOOK='PERFORM'
AND ((pdr.FISCAL_YEAR=2014 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD=11) 
OR (pdr.FISCAL_YEAR=2014 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD=10))

group by
pa.business_unit,
pa.descr,
pdr.deptid,
pdr.asset_id,
pdr.account_ad,
pdr.book

order by
pdr.asset_id
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

SQL # 2

```
select
asset_id
account,
journal_id,
journal_date

from ps_dist_ln 

where
book = 'PERFORM'
and business_unit = 'A0465'
and fiscal_year = 2014
and accounting_period = 11
and distribution_type = 'DE'
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, just join the additional table.

```
SELECT 
    pa.BUSINESS_UNIT, 
    pa.DESCR,
    pdr.DEPTID, 
    pdr.ASSET_ID, 
    pdr.ACCOUNT_AD, 
    pdr.BOOK,

    MAX(CASE WHEN (pdr.FISCAL_YEAR =2014 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =11) THEN  pdr.DEPR END) as CURRENT_AMT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (pdr.FISCAL_YEAR =2104 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =10) THEN pdr.DEPR  END) as PRIOR_AMT,

    pdl.journal_id,
    pdl.journal_date

FROM PS_ASSET pa

INNER JOIN PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 
    ON pa.ASSET_ID = pdr.ASSET_ID
    AND pa.BUSINESS_UNIT = pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT

LEFT JOIN ps_dist_ln pdl
    ON pdl.ASSET_ID = pdr.ASSET_ID
    AND pdl.book = pdr.book
    AND pdl.fiscal_year = pdr.fiscal_year
    AND pdl.accounting_period = pdr.accounting_period

WHERE 
    pa.BUSINESS_UNIT=A0465
    AND pdr.BOOK='PERFORM'
    AND ((pdr.FISCAL_YEAR=2014 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD=11) 
        OR (pdr.FISCAL_YEAR=2014 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD=10))
    and pdl.business_unit = 'A0465'
    and pdl.distribution_type = 'DE'

group by
    pa.business_unit,
    pa.descr,
    pdr.deptid,
    pdr.asset_id,
    pdr.account_ad,
    pdr.book

order by
    pdr.asset_id
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this but I'm not getting any amounts in the prior_amt column.

Comment: I've changed the new join to `LEFT JOIN`, so you'll get rows that don't have any match in `ps_dist_ln` in the result.